# How do I get the value of the div when I click on it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, alert

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FirstName from './firstName';
import LastName from './lastName';
import styles from './styles';

const handleClick = () => {
    alert('was clicked');
}

export default class Vishal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activity: "play"
    }
  }


  render() {
      return <div>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          {
            this.props.names.map(function(name) {
              return <div onClick={handleClick} style={styles.namesContainer}>
              <div style={styles.firstMargin}><FirstName firstName={name.firstName}></FirstName></div>
              <div><LastName lastName={name.lastName}></LastName></div>
              </div>
            })
          }
      </div>

    }
}
```

I have different names which are coming dynamically and the divs look like this

[image]

This is the layout and when I click on any div it should show the respective name on alert
It should say for example 'Vishal Mishra was clicked' on alert

Comment: Which version of react are you using, if its greater than 16 and if you are using create react app then you can avoid constructor. I have added the answer assuming you are using latest version

Answer (score 2):

First, you can keep the `handleClick` function within the class and reference it with `this.handleClick` and secondly you need to pass the data you want to display in the `onClick` props like this `onClick={() => this.handleClick(name)`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import FirstName from './firstName';
import LastName from './lastName';
import styles from './styles';

export default class Vishal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activity: "play"
    }
  }

  handleClick = (name) => {
    alert(name.FirstName + ' was clicked');
  }

  render() {
      return <div>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          {
            this.props.names.map((name, key) => {
              return (
                <div onClick={() => this.handleClick(name)} style={styles.namesContainer} key={key}>
                  <div style={styles.firstMargin}><FirstName firstName={name.firstName}></FirstName></div>
                  <div><LastName lastName={name.lastName}></LastName></div>
                </div>
              )
            })
          }
      </div>

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have the `handleClick` function inside the Vishal class or outside? if it's outside remove the `this` in the onClick function call.

Comment: Great! To display full name, you can do `alert(name.FirstName +  '  '  +  name.LastName +  ' was clicked');` If it solves your problem you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: Can anyone explain how exactly is the 'name' parameter accessing the values of the names and only giving us the names on the basis of the clicked div?

Comment: I have edited the code to include a `key` to the mapped elements as react expects every element in the map function to have a unique key. The `map()` function is an array method similar to `forEach()` which is used to loop over each item in an array and do something with them. If you still find this confusing, you may need to do some reading on array methods and Event handlers [DOM onevent handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)

Answer (score 1):

You can try giving the name as parameter to the `handleClick` function.

```
onClick={() => handleClick(name)}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it says [object Object] was clicked

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the name, you can do as like this

```
onClick={() => handleClick(name)}
```

Sample Code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const handleClick = name => {
  alert(`You clicked on ${name.firstName} ${name.lastName}`);
};

export default class Vishal extends Component {
  state = {
    activity: "play",
    names: [
      { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" },
      { firstName: "Jef", lastName: "Jacob" }
    ]
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        {this.state.names.map(function(name) {
          return (
            <div onClick={() => handleClick(name)}>
              {`${name.firstName} ${name.lastName}`}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Vishal />, rootElement);
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59286206-so-s9lh3)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but I want an alert with the full name in it.

Comment: Updated kindly check :)

Comment: Thanks, this is fine

Comment: If it worked for you kindly accept and upvote so it will be helpful for others. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

PLease find below code snippet, you have to bind `handleClick` :

```js
export default class Vishal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activity: "play"
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick = (name) => {
      alert(name + 'was clicked');
  }

  render() {
      return <div>
          <h1>Hello</h1>
          {
            this.props.names.map(function(name) {
              return <div onClick={this.handleClick(name.firstName)} style={styles.namesContainer}>
              <div style={styles.firstMargin}><FirstName firstName={name.firstName}></FirstName></div>
              <div><LastName lastName={name.lastName}></LastName></div>
              </div>
            })
          }
      </div>

    }
}
```